# Python: One file, various data: How to extract multiple measurements from one .txt file? (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file that contains different sections (steps) of a measurement. The number of steps is usually between 1 and 10. It has the following structure:

```
Mainheader of the measurement (contains the test parameters of each step, thus the length is individual for every measurement)

Step 1
Time    Displacement    Force *-> the separators are tabs in this file*
*blank row*
[s]    [mm]    [N]
Data
Data
Data
...
*blank row*
Step 2
Time    Displacement    Force
*blank row*
[s]    [mm]    [N]
*no data*
*blank row*
Step 3
Time    Displacement    Force
*blank row*
[s]    [mm]    [N]
Data
Data
Data
...
*blank row*
Step4
Time    Displacement    Force
*blank row*
[s]    [mm]    [N]
*no data*
*blank row*
```

The number of steps is not defined and can vary between different measurements. I want to extract the data of each step and save it to data frame and in a later stage to a .txt file (-> Test1_step1.txt, Test1_step2.txt, ...). What I have also to consider is that not every step contains data so the data frame, in this case, should be skipped (e.g. *no data* in step 2 and step 4).

My idea was to load the file with  `with open(...)` and go through each line with a `for` statement and append all lines between the row of the unit ([s] [mm] [N]) and a blank row to an empty list (*data* in this case). If the end of a step is reached (*blank line*) the list should be converted to a df (df should also have the index of the step number) and the program proceeds with the next line. *The reason why I want to use pandas is that some values are `nan` and I heard pandas can handle this very well*. In the end, I want separate data frames which contain the data of each step e.g. df_1 (contains data from step 1), df_3 (contains data from step 3), and so on.

I've tried to tackle the problems step by step and used the following code to isolate at least the first step but I just got a df that contains all my data without any blank lines.

```
data = []

with open(file, 'r') as f: 
    for line in f:
        if '[s]' in line: # Starting point of the data
            for line in f: # go through each line 
                if line in ['\n','\r\n']: # checks if the line is empty
                    df = pd.DataFrame(data) # should save data to a data frame and continue with the next line
                    break
                
                else:
                    data.append(line) # if line is not empty append to data
```

Maybe someone can help me with my problem(s). Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: No time to write out a solution... but you get a single `df` because you are creating a single `data` list and continually over-writing `df` with a `pd.DataFrame` of the latest, ever increasing `data` list. If you want separate dataframes for each step, you need to save off each of the dataframes to separate variables (append to another list, or add to a dict) and reset `data` before saving the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
data = []
stepnumber = 0

with open(file, 'r') as f: 
    line = f.readline()
    while len(line) > 0:     # assuming last line has a newline, it'll be ''
        # check for "Step N" line: read step number
        if line.startswith("Step"):
            stepnumber = int(line[4:].strip())

        elif '[s]' in line:    # Starting point of the data
            line = f.readline().strip()
            while not line == "": # go through each non-empty data line 
                data.append(line)
                line = f.readline().strip()

            # after that loop, we have an empty data line
            # save data to a data frame and continue with the next line
            if len(data) > 0:
                df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                with open(f"Test1_step{stepnumber}.txt", 'w') as ofh:
                    ofh.write(df)
                data = []


        # continue to next line
        line = f.readline()
```

This should write out a file `Test1_step<stepnumber>.txt` for each non-empty step containing the data frame for that step. If instead you want to do more processing and write the files later, perhaps you'll want to append the dataframes to a list or something (maybe in a tuple including the step number).

You may need more error checking to handle your real data. This loop does handle steps without data.

Comment: Thank you very much @DraftyHat. Your skript was a good start for me and helped me a lot. I had to adopt your code to my demands (data) but now I got the desired result. You saved me a lot of time (and nerves). ;)

Comment: Nice! That's great to hear!